# Prove that the set of a product space is closed.

Tags: general-topology

Given that $(r_n) \rightarrow 0 $ is a null sequence of **irrational** numbers in $\underline R$. 
Also $(s_{n,m}) \rightarrow r_n$ is a sequence of **rational** numbers in $\underline R$.

Prove that: $$ A = \left\{ \left(n + \frac 1 m,\ s_{n,m} \right) \ | \ n \in N, m \in N, m \ge 2 \right\} $$
is a **closed** in $\underline R \times \underline Q$.

I guess we have to show that $A$ is sequentially-closed or that any convergent sequence from it converges to the element of $A$. I'm not sure how to do that in the case of product spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $A$ is discrete, meaning for any point you can find an open ball around it which contains only the point. This is because the set $\frac{1}{m}$ is discrete, and so is $s_{n,m}$ for any fixed $n$ since the only limit point of a converging sequence is it's limit, in this case the limit is irrational hence not in the product topology.

It is important to notice the set $A$ is not closed in the product $\mathbb{R}$, since the points $(n,r_n)$ would be limit points of $A$, but not in $A$.

To be a bit more detailed, for any $(n_0+\frac{1}{m_0},s_{n_0,m_0})\in A$ consider the ball of radius $\frac{1}{m_0+1}$ around $n_0+\frac{1}{m_0}$ and the ball of radius inf$_{\forall m}|s_{n_0,m_0}-s_{n_0,m}|$ which exists since $r_n$ is irrational, and converging sequences, have exactly one limit point.

Comment: Could you describe the part starting from "the ball of radius ... which exists since $r_n$ is irrational" in more detail? I can't see how it glues together. I can see that for any $s_{n_0,m_0}$ you're getting distances to every other $s_{n,m}$ and then take the $inf$ of that to build this very small open ball. What I don't get is why the ball exists just because $r_n$ is irrational.

Comment: Sure, it's because limit points of a converging limit are unique. If the point $s_{n_0,m_0}$ couldn't fit a ball around it excluding all other points in the sequence, then it'd be by definition a limit point of the sequence. But a sequence which converges can't have two limit points, only sequences like $(-1)^n$ can have two limit points.

Comment: @СССР Sure, it's because limit points of a converging limit are unique. If the point $s_{n_0,m_0}$ couldn't fit a ball around it excluding all other points in the sequence, then it'd be by definition a limit point of the sequence. But a sequence which converges can't have two limit points, only sequences like $(−1)^n$ can have two limit points.